# Sort out values not in range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range in [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zpVtQXc8wZ8IejCnbBL1I6Y62aKuMu01JgqUgXrmVcg/edit?usp=sharing) in which each of the cells may contain a number between 1 and 12.

In a different area of the spreadsheet I want to list all the numbers between 1 and 12 which does not appear in the range.

I was thinking of doing it using `sumproduct` with one vector containing 0 or 1 depending on whether I can find a match, and the other the numbers between 1 and 12. However I am having some trouble in generating the first of these vectors.

I think using `query` would also work, but I am unfamiliar with using queries, so I thought the sumproduct-approach might be easier.

Either way, I am stuck. Can someone please give me a pointer for how I may best solve my problem?

I'd prefer solving the problem without using any scripts.

I attach a screenshot of the worksheet below, or you can visit it using the link at the beginning of my question. The area to search is B2:F9.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `filter()` function with the `isna(match())` pattern, like this:

```
=filter( 
  sequence(12), 
  isna( 
    match( 
      sequence(12), 
      flatten(B2:F9), 
      0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To get a comma-separated list, wrap the formula in `join()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked like a charm :-)